# Content getting swapped for multiple sessions users in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, static-methods, pagemethods

I am developing an asp.net website.

- When two different users are accessing that website with different sessions, one users content is getting swapped to another user.
- I am using javacsript, calling pagemethods from .aspx pages and C# at code behind.
- This problem mainly occuring when two users are calling same functionality at a time.
- I thought static variables could cause this problem and tried not to use any static variables or static functions except for pagemethod functions where it is manadatory for a pagemethod to be static.

please help me out with this problem.

Comment: Could you post an example of the code?

Comment: Is this site behind a load balancer? Is your session stored in process or in a database?

Comment: @Damon this is not related to a particular block of code.. this problem occurs in wherever a static variable is used. i tried to avoid static variables and static methods, but for pagemethods it is mandatory to have static function. still if u need sample code, i will provide it.

Answer (score 5):

Could also be related to threading. [Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) those variables up and see if that helps.

Static methods do not guarantee static variable state even though the methods are guaranteed to be thread-safe. You have to manage that state and asp.net treats static variables as shared amongst all users. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435093/112397) from a related question.

More reading: [Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx)

Comment: Locking the static variables/static functions is fine, but when n number of users accessing the same functionality, then this locking may cause website to be slow, right?

Comment: The cost will in most cases be negligible, I've rarely encountered a scenario where I've had to go back and optimize. But when you do you start looking at thread syncronization its a whole new world. Lots of complicated fun stuff like [Semaphores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) and [Mutexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

Comment: Sorry for all the comments Hulk but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154551/volatile-vs-interlocked-vs-lock) is really the one you want to read, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673618/how-expensive-is-the-lock-statement) answers your question about speed - but the short answer is 50ns.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem, and found that it was our loadbalancer(f5 Big-IP) that messed up the session-ids. We changed the loadbalancer to be stateful, and it now functions perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

- turn on the aspnet state service in windows services.
- use session["x"] instead of Static x
- use viewstate["x"] for page level values

Answer (score 1):

Check your session state configuration (see example below). 
Perhaps you use another mode than "InProc" and running in some problems with that.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
```

You could also consider using caching instances with keys that using the SessionID as prefix.
The enterprise library offers a good caching implementation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

remove you static variable and static method use to respond your request.

Answer (score 1):

**Add `sessionState` in web.config:**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <sessionState timeout="120" mode=" [InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]" cookieless="false"  />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Try also the following solution:**

1. Start>Administrative Tools>Services
2. right click on ASP.NET State Service and click 'start'.

Variables also need to LOCK as mentioned in [@TombMedia's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18779642/49942).

This link may be help you: [Exploring Session in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net)

Answer (score 0):

this is to be set in Web.config and <%@ outputcache duration="1" varybyparam="none" %> this to be removed all the .aspx Forms..

Regards
Rs