# Storing a value globally across all pages

Tags: asp.net

This is an ASP.NET Forms project.  When user enters his/her user name and password (in the Login page) I want to save the user name such that it can be retrieved in the code of any page of the project. I know that I can do it via a session variable.
But is it possible to create a Static Public class with Get Set and store the value there and retrieve it using this class?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, static classes are shared by all instances/sessions of your app.  Therefore, using a static class probably isn't a good idea for a user name because its entirely plausible to see a situation where one user's name shows up on another user's screen...

Comment: @ajax81  Thank you. I didn't realize that static classes store the values on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using master page create a hidden field in that store that information in that hidden value so you can access in any page where you are using that master page.

Comment: I do use master page. And I will Google on how to create a hidden field.  Thank you.

Comment: Muhammad, thank you for your help and link.  I will vote once I review all the options.

Comment: This is not even near being help. Explain how and why a master page is needed for OPs scenario as well as a hidden field...

Answer (score 0):

Static classes are shared across instances/sessions in your app, which means you could end up with something akin to race conditions; for instance, a request from User_A could read values that were set in your static class by User_B.  (see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435093/183624))

Shooting from the hip, it might be easier to write a wrapper/abstraction class for your users' info that makes accessing their details easier.  Something like:

```
public class UserDetails{

   public string Name;
   public string Age;
   public string Gender;

   public UserDetails(HttpContext context){
      this.Name   = context.User.Identity.Name;
      this.Age    = ...;
      this.Gender = ...;

      // Alternatively, you could perform your own data access to
      // get/set these details. It depends on how you're storing your
      // users' info.
   }
}
```

Then in your code behind...

```
UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails(context.Current);
Response.Write(userDetails.Name); // user's name
Response.Write(userDetails.Age); // user's age
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the sample code. I will see how to apply it in my case.

Comment: "Static classes are shared across instances/sessions in your app", this is only true when you are working with one server.

Comment: @Jacob You're right, but the op's intention to store user-specific data in static variables means there will still be collisions between users if the data is not stored in a keyed collection.  Plus, the landscape of deployable architectures out there is variable enough that I think we can all agree there are better ways to store session state than in static variables shared by all users on a server.